# How to display grouped data with Collection View in C# MAUI

Tags: c#, maui

I'm reading student data from a database and would like to display it in a grouped collection view, however, I cannot figure out how to write the collection view.

This code returns the proper attendance records you'll see below in the debug output:

```
public class AttendanceGroup : List<Attendance>
{
    public string GroupName { get; private set; }

    public AttendanceGroup(string name, List<Attendance> attendees) : base(attendees)
    {
        GroupName = name;
    }
}

public class Attendance
{
    public int aID { get; set; }
    public DateTime aDate { get; set; }
    public string aStudent_Name { get; set; }
    public int sID_Link { get; set; }
    public string aClass_Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime aClass_Start_Time { get; set; }
    public string aInstructor { get; set; }
}

ObservableCollection<AttendanceGroup> attendanceGroups = DatabaseHelper.GetAttendanceGroupsData(connectionString, selectedDate);
foreach (AttendanceGroup attendanceGroup in attendanceGroups)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(">>>> " + attendanceGroup.GroupName);
    foreach (Attendance attendance in attendanceGroup) 
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("   ---- " + attendance.aStudent_Name);
    }
}
```

Debug Output:

```
>>>> grp_9:30AM_Class
   ---- Becky
   ---- Cindy
   ---- Dan
   ---- Dave
   ---- Dawn
   ---- Matt
   ---- Melissa
   ---- Nichole
   ---- Susan
   ---- Tina
   ---- Zak
>>>> grp_5:00PM_Class
   ---- Michele
   ---- Susan
```

Problem is that my XAML  is not working.  Here it is:

```
            <CollectionView x:Name="collectionView">
                <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Text="{Binding GroupName}" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,10" Padding="10,10,10,10" MinimumHeightRequest="60">
                            <Label Text="{Binding aStudent_Name}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

I get an error for aStudent_Name that prevents it from displaying anything.  Here's the error:

```
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Diagnostics.BindingDiagnostics: Warning: 'aStudent_Name' property not found on 'Attendance, Attendance, Attendance, Attendance, Attendance, Attendance, Attendance, Attendance, Attendance, Attendance, Attendance', target property: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Label.Text'
```

Next, if I comment out the entire DataTemplate section (where the aStudent_Name error is coming from) then I get CollectionView output that looks like this:

```
AttendanceGroup
AttendanceGroup
```

Can you help me figure out how to write this Collection View to show my data grouped in the same manner I have in my debug window?

Comment: try specifying a `DataType` on the `DataTemplate`

Comment: you are also missing `IsGrouped="true"` on the `CollectionView`

Comment: @Jason Adding ```IsGrouped="true"``` fixed it!  Please post as possible answer and I'll select it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to use grouping you must set the `IsGrouped` property

```
<CollectionView IsGrouped="True">
```

Comment: Sometimes it's just something simple ~ thanks!